# Vue.js progress bar with values from API call

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-4

I've got a simple component that pulls data from an API and I would like to add a progress bar that indicates the next data refresh. The API calls are done with a 10 seconds interval and data itself is usually refreshed every minute.

The value for the progress bar is based on date: `2018-12-04T16:10:09.508367Z` where I retrieve seconds using`moment` library: `moment().diff(2018-12-04T16:10:09.508367Z, 'seconds')`

Because this can be a random value the steps for the progress bar are not equal and they don't start from a full bar.

I was wondering if there is a way to improve this?

This is my pseudo [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/1qm56m8o2q?expanddevtools=1&module=%2Fsrc%2Fcomponents%2FProgressBar.vue) on codesandbox to illustrate that.

```
<template>
  <b-container fluid>
    <b-row>
      <b-col md="12" class="p-0 fixed-top">
        <b-progress
          :value="progressCounter"
          :max="progressMax"
          height="5px"
          variant="warning"
        >
        </b-progress>
      </b-col>
    </b-row>
    <b-row>
      <b-col md="12" class="">
        {{ progressMax }} / {{ progressCounter }}
      </b-col>
    </b-row>
  </b-container>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "ProgressBar",
  data() {
    return {
      progressCounter: 60,
      progressMax: 60,
      interval: null,
      refresh: 10000,
      time: 0
    };
  },
  methods: {
    getRandomInt(min, max) {
      min = Math.ceil(min);
      max = Math.floor(max);
      return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    },
    progress() {
      /*
      this.time is just a pseudo code here, the real progressCounter is recived from
      an API call and seconds are calculated by deducting time from now:
      this.progressCounter = 60 - moment().diff(created, 'seconds')
      "created" comes from an API call and it's refreshed (~) every minute
      */
      if (this.time <= 10) {
        this.time = this.getRandomInt(40, 59);
      } else {
        this.time -= 10;
      }
      this.progressCounter = this.time;
      console.log(
        `this.time: ${this.time}, this.progressCounter: ${this.progressCounter}`
      );
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    this.interval = setInterval(
      function() {
        this.progress();
      }.bind(this),
      this.refresh
    );
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    clearInterval(this.interval);
  }
};
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped></style>
```

Comment: Looks like this would be better suited for codereview:  https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @DerekPollard Pseudo-code does not qualify for Code Review.

Comment: @MathiasEttinger his codepen is working code.